# Does deleting a node from a biconnected graph keep the remaining graph biconnected?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

When a node is deleted from a biconnected graph, the graph remain is still connected.
The question is does deleting any single node from a biconnected graph necessarily  result in a biconnected graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Think of the graph with 4 nodes `{a,b,c,d}` with the following edges:

`(a,b), (b,c), (c,d), (d,a)`

This is a biconnected graph, but removing any node will make it no longer biconnected.